# Help lost all lights in the house!

Tags: lighting

Can anyone help me, I've tried to wire up a light today and I've lost all power to the general lighting in the house!

I re wired one light previously, reading on forums I had to set up the 3 cables as all red together in a box, 2 black cables to blue and the one black cable (switch) to the brown terminal. Everything worked fine.

I've tried to do the same today and when I tried the light the circuit breaker went. I undid the wired and now none of the lights in the house work.

Do I need to re wire the 3 white cables together or have I completely screwed all of our lighting in the house???[image]

Comment: Pictures of what you worked will help a lot.  Also, after you undid the wires in the affected box, did you isolate them and reset the circuit breaker?   Also, please use the terms "cables" and "wires" correctly so we can better help you.  Cables contain more than one wire, while wires are individual conductors.

Comment: Cannot help without more information and pictures.  Light circuits come in many different arrangements, single light with switch to multiable lights controlled by different switches.

Comment: Country may be important. Blue is a relatively unusual color in US wiring, implying either US with conduit or some other country. Colors mean different things in different places.

Comment: OK so there are 3 cables from the ceiling each have 3 wires, each has a red, a black and a copper wire.

Comment: Not sure how to add a photo

Comment: I've added a picture. So after the breaker tripped I went back downstairs, could see it had tripped, unwired the light and returned the cables as I found them originally (picture attached). Something has gone wrong and none of the lights work

Comment: You didn't answer the question - did you reset the breakers - every one in the box includes the main.

Comment: Thank you, I turned every breaker off and then turned them all back on again and the power to lights has come back on. Just in time to put the baby to bed, thank you so much for everyone's help, I think I'll get someone who knows what they are doing round to install the light!!!

Comment: Probably tripped an RCD then.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Golden rule - if all you're doing is changing a ceiling rose & unless you're reconfiguring/replacing the actual house cabling, all you should need to do is replace what you took out with the old light with the equivalent in the new light. The rest is untouched.

Your wires all go in the other face of the terminal block, in the same holes as the old ones came out. If the old ones were red & black, which is the old pre-1977 colour scheme, the new cable will be brown(live), blue(neutral), green/yellow(earth).
Brown==red, blue==black, green/yellow==bare. Your existing double-black there is the loop, the single black is the switch circuit, so you should be wiring into the live, switched & earth, not the loop.